# iphone - On orientation change of iphone , rotate only one control and not all others

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, orientation

I'm having UIImageView, few lables, buttons etc in a view.
Currently I have implementation for portrait mode.
When orientation of iphone is changed, I just want to rotate only image view. Rest all other controls should not change.
How can I implement the rotation of only image view?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something very similar recently. What I did was disable auto rotation and then used the device notifications like this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {  
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    switch (orientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationUnknown:
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp:
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown:
            return;
            break;
    }

    // Do something
}
```

You will need to handle some situations like quick rotations etc. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But needs little clarification. Do I have to create different view class that inherits from ImageView and handle it or I can handle "didRotate" in viewController itself?

Comment: My suggestion would be to handle this in the view controller. Perhaps setup the observer in your viewDidLoad. The notifications will be sent immediately for _any_ orientation changes. So I save the orientation change and set the animation on it's way. If there is another orientation change during the animation I start the animation all over again until there are no changes.